# Django new user with email confirm

Tags: python, django

I am super new to Django and currently working on a training project. 
Question 1 - I want new registered user can receive a confirm email. Referring to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/, I create my User model as below and I hope create_user() in UserManager been called on new user creation but it turns out it never been called. Is my implementation wrong?

```
from authtools.models import AbstractEmailUser
from django.db import models

from authtools.models import UserManager as BaseUserManager
from mysite.models import UserType
from mysite.models import Organisation


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(**kwargs)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.user_type = UserType.objects.get(name='ADMIN')
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = super().create_user(email, password, kwargs)
        user.email_user("Register Confirm", "welcome", "admin@mysite.com")


class User(AbstractEmailUser):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(UserType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
```

Question 2 - Can anybody explains how Django framework works on triggering to create a new user? Say receiving api call /users/add, how create_user() been called?

Comment: Have you created `UserCreationForm` mentioned on that page?

Comment: No, the project intents to use api calls to trigger actions.

Comment: Please include your `/users/add` serializer and the view function as well.

Comment: code is on company computer and I do not have it now. User serializer is just extends from serializers.ModelSerializer with given fields in Meta. view function is on React side and POST /users to add new user. Are you suggesting email_user() should be invoked in serializer?

Comment: No, create_user should be invoked in the serializer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You right!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to Daniel Roseman, the solution is overriding create() in my User Serializer. Thanks!